# Find sequence pattern in transactions using python

Tags: python, data-mining

I have data in the given form:

```
Date       | Products
2014-01-01 | A,B,C,D
2014-01-02 | M,N
2014-01-03 | B,X
2014-01-06 | M
2014-02-07 | F,B
2014-02-09 | M,A
```

I want to use some algorithm to identify that M is mostly bought after B, i.e. B and M have some association. Has anyone here ever solved some problem of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

1. make them in one list

like [A,B,C,D,M,N,B,X,M,F,B,M,A]

2. make it weighted.

The first char behind M weights 1, the second one weights 2, till the next M.

3. sum them up.

the char with lightest weight wins. (which means has some association in your word.)